# Problems using GNU Scientific Library in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, gsl

I'm having some issues trying to install GSL for my programming course at uni (the course is taught in C). I'm using Visual Studio express 2012.

I've downloaded and run a precompiled GSL thing (GnuWin32) and changed my Linker and Includes options in VS, and the code is actually running properly. I've been using the following code as an example:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_blas.h>

int main()
{
  size_t i,j;

  gsl_matrix *m;
  m = gsl_matrix_alloc (10, 10);

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
      gsl_matrix_set (m, i, j, sin (i) + cos (j));
    }
  }

  for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
  {
    gsl_vector_view column = gsl_matrix_column (m, j);
    double d;

    d = gsl_blas_dnrm2 (&column.vector);

    printf ("matrix column %d, norm = %g\n", j, d);
  }

  gsl_matrix_free(m);
}
```

This *is* running properly and giving me the correct output. However, when VS gets to the final curly bracket, it freaks out and gives me this error message:

"Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention."

Does anyone have an idea how to stop this happening? I've scoured the internet, and haven't found anything useful that I can understand.

Comment: It helps to format code so you can see the indentation level and what error message, this should be here on not on a link that could change

Comment: Please only use images here when absolutely necessary to illustrate your problem. The content is not searchable, they often can't load due to proxy configuration, and they're larger than they need to be for people with limited bandwidth/data. Copy the text into your question instead. Thanks.

Comment: 1. Does the error persist if you omit the last `gsl_matrix_free(m);`?  2. You are missing a `return 0`, as main() needs to return an int (since this is C89 code).

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Yeah the error is still happening when omitting the last gsl_matrix_free(m);. Also get the error when I return 0, or change the function to a void type.

Answer (score 0):

'ESP was not saved properly' sounds like the standard asm code to save ESP into EBP failed or was not generated. There is a compiler option 'Omit frame pointers'. Check how it is set in your build for both the library and your main code. They both must be built the same way. Also, if you want a debugger to work, then uncheck this option.

Comment: Omit frame pointer shouldn't matter - ESP should be preserved with or without frame pointers.